# Exception on insertion in android database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

An UnknownFormatConversionException is thrown on the calling of the insert function just after the for loop and the printing of the Log, i caught that exception but how to remove it? I do'nt know what the reason it happened,

```
try {
        List<Status> timeline = 
            ((YambaApp) getApplication()).getTwitter().getPublicTimeline();
        for (Status status : timeline) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s: %s", status.user.name,
                    status.text));
            statusData.insert(status);

            }
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Failed to access twitter service  ",e);
    } catch(NullPointerException a){
        Log.d(TAG,"Pref had been changed and twitter object is null",a);
    } catch (UnknownFormatConversionException u){
        Log.d(TAG,"exception "+ u);
    }
```

Here is the Code of the insert function:

```
public void insert(Status status){
    db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues value= new ContentValues();
    //converting BigInteger to String
    BigInteger bi=status.id;
    String status_id= new String(bi.toByteArray());


    value.put(C_ID, status_id);
    value.put(C_CREATED_AT, status.createdAt.getTime());
    value.put(C_TEXT, status.user.name);
    value.put(C_TEXT, status.text);

    db.insert(TABLE, null, value);
}
```

Here is the complete stack trace of the thrown exception

```
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RefreshService]
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: i
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1397)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at     java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1334)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1440)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1079)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1040)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1009)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1998)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1972)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.yamba.StatusData$DbHelper.onCreate(StatusData.java:59)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:165)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.yamba.StatusData.insert(StatusData.java:32)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.yamba.RefreshService.onHandleIntent(RefreshService.java:32)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 06:05:22.648: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-10 06:05:22.968: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(627): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Well, what *was* the exception?

Comment: UnknownFormatConversionException: conversion : i

Comment: 10-09 23:44:24.744: D/RefreshService(1493): exception java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: i

Comment: Is status.user.name a string? Your format statement expects a string %s

Comment: Beyond the fact that you're some how inserting two values with the same key into the ContentValues, CTEXT, I think the arguements you're passing into the log aren't correct.

Comment: status.user.name is a string, the Log is not a problem, it is printing once but when it reached the insert function call an exception is thrown, the problem is surely there because when i comment it out it run perfectly, somewhere inside the function declaration and its call the problem is there, but can't find it

Comment: If you want to see exactly where the exception is being thrown, just remove your `catch (UnknownFormatConversionException u)` clause. Then you will get a stack trace that shows exactly where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

In your `insert()` method change

```
String status_id= new String(bi.toByteArray());
```

to

```
String status_id = bi.toString();
```

Calling `bi.toByteArray()` is going to return you a byte array containing the binary representation of the `BigInteger`. You can't convert this into a `String` properly the way you are doing it. Just use the provided `toString()` method of `BigInteger`.